# What is the difference between "functions" and "function-like entities" in C++ algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

In C++20 the new namespace `std::ranges` was added to the standard, with many algorithms there duplicating already-existing ones, e.g. `std::find_if` and `std::ranges::find_if`. On the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) the "old" algorithms are called "functions", and the "new" - "function-like entities". Yet, I can't use it in a "functional" way, e.g.

```cpp
auto result = myMapObj
                | std::ranges::views::keys
                | std::ranges::find_if([](const auto& key) { return key == 42; });
```

I need to use it the same way as the good old `std::find_if`. So what is the difference, and which one should I choose in which case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're global objects with overloaded `operator()`.

There are some marginal benefits in designing them this way (compared to function templates), e.g. being able to pass them as arguments to other functions (`foo(std::ranges::find_if)`) using a sane syntax (to pass `std::find_if` in this manner you'd need to wrap it in a lambda).

> which one should I choose in which case?

You should always prefer the `std::ranges::...` versions, assuming your standard library implementation supports them.

Comment: Other advantages include the possibility to actually hide implementation details as private member functions. And the best perk of all: no ADL. When using such an object, the caller cannot bypass it via ADL (either voluntarily or not..): this is really great because that way you can actually enforce type checks at all times!

Comment: "*being able to pass them as arguments to other functions*" This is not true, niebloid does not guarantee objectness, although currently they can only be implemented in the form of objects. This lack of guarantee does nothing good by making it inconvenient for users, which is why MSVC-STL recently planned to turn it into a copyable CPO in [#4097](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/4097).